# How to restart particular IIS site from Multiple IIS sites?

Tags: deployment, iis-7, web, cruisecontrol.net, multiple-projects

In our company we have multiple projects in single IIS server and I am working on build automation via using CruisControl. My question is I have to restart a particular IIS site after deployment without entering into server or Via using CruiseControl jobs.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Well I got answer for this :) So I used a batch script for IIS Stop/Start and executed it from CruiseControl Dashboard. You can use below batch script if you do not have Admin permission for appcmd execution.

** Below location is default in all system (may be defer)

create separate batch file for Stop and Start and Run it from CCnet job.

`"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd stop site qwerty"` -- **Stops** Site 'qwerty'

`"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd start site qwerty"` -- **Starts** Site 'qwerty'

let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can start an individual Web site without affecting the operation of any other Web site that is being that is supported by a server that is maintained by Internet Services Manager.

To start an individual Web site that has previously been stopped:

- Log on to the Web server computer as an administrator.
- Click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
- Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet
  Services Manager.
- Right-click the Web site that you want to start in the left pane, and
  then click Start.

***CommandLine:***

Command Line
To start or stop a Web site, use the following syntax:

```
appcmd start | stop site /site.name:string
```

The variable string is the name of the Web site that you want to start or stop.
For example, to stop a Web site named contoso, type the following at the command prompt, and then press ENTER:

```
appcmd stop site /site.name: contoso
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Thanks this helps but as I dont have Admin access to server not able to execute this command over there. it worked fine on my local. Any idea how to do this with CrusiControl?

Comment: great.. You are welcome :)...  In CrusiControl I didn't find rememeber any direct way to achieve this.. however if I will find anything I will add that one too...

Answer (score 1):

I found no method for now to restart any site individually, however using
**IISAdministration** power shell module we can automate process or we can have use into our script to auto restart a site

```
Stop-IISSite -Name $web -Confirm:$false   #$web provide IIS site name
```

Once site is stopped you can start again(restart)

```
Start-IISSite -Name $web
```